# What does the subscript n on methylene groups in a cyclic alkene mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I've recently come across an unfamiliar notation on a cyclic alkane. One carbon had parentheses around it with a subscript $n$. Does this refer to rings of variable sizes (i.e.  one or more $\ce{CH2}$ groups are located in this position)? If not, what does this refer to?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, n denotes the number of $\ce{CH2}$ groups between the parentheses.

Example:
[image]

n = 1, 2 or 4 means cyclopentane, cyclohexane, or cyclooctane.

Comment: So, just to clarify, this means that the ring (drawn as cyclohexane) could actually represent a cyclopentane or cycloheptane, etc. as indicated by the subscript? Therefore, this would not represent a group attached to the ring that is not, itself, part of the cyclic structure?

Comment: The parenthesized group with the subscript is repeated n times. So if cyclohexane is drawn, the repetition of a $\ce{CH2}$ migth result in cyclohexane (n = 1) or bigger rings. I've added an example to illustrate this.